# Why is $\operatorname{Hom}\left(\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z} \right) \simeq \prod_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, direct-product

So I was working on a few exercises. Eventually I came across this isomorphism

$$\operatorname{Hom}\left(\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z} \right) \simeq \prod_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$$

and I was wondering if someone could help me understand this in detail. I have issues understanding the map itself and particularly seeing how such isomorphism (canonically) might look like. What's the obvious choice here (if there is any)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What part of it is confusing you?

Comment: Writing down what an element of each of these things look like can make one candidate 
isomorphism stand out almost immediately.

Comment: This was my issue. Maybe it's trivial. But on the left hand side an element is simply a homomorphism $\varphi\colon \oplus_n \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ and on the right hand side i have these pairs with countably many elements $(m_1,m_2,m_3,...)$.

Is the key observation here that i can express each element $k \in \prod \mathbb{Z}$ as a unique product $\prod m_i$ with $m_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ (each factor) ?

Comment: Zest, the point is that we can define a homomorphism $\phi$ by declaring that $\phi(e_i)=m_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th element of the obvious basis. IOW $e_i=(0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ with the single $1$ at position $i$, $i=\in\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: Extending that to a well defined map from all of $X=\bigoplus_{\Bbb{N}}\Bbb{Z}$ poses no problems, because any element $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ of $X$ has only finitely many non-zero components $x_i$. Therefore the sum $\phi(x)=\sum_i x_im_i$ is well defined. It has only finitely many non-zero terms even though there may be infinitely many non-zero $m_i$s.

Comment: Thanks for the help @JyrkiLahtonen. Your approach seems to be the basis for the answers i've receveid so far which definitely helps (i just need to sleep one night over all this). I am curious: The "obvious" assignment $\varphi(x) = \sum_i x_i m_i$ is given because $X$ is a free abelian group(i.e. has a basis) right? Assuming $X = G$ any ordinary group (not free abelian), this would not be working, would it?

Comment: Correct, @Zest. A key fact is that the $x_i$s are linearly independent over $\Bbb{Z}$. If they were replaced with a random collection of generators of some other abelian group $X$, then they might satisfy some (possibly hidden) linear dependency relations. And any homomorphism would need to "respect that relation" (i.e. it would yield a relation that the homomorphic images must also satisfy).

Comment: Beautiful, that's indeed quite helpfull. Thanks for your consideration @JyrkiLahtonen. The answers certainly help too, i will accept either of them by tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a = (a_1, a_2, ...) \in \prod_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}$. Then define
$$\phi_a : \bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$$
in the obvious way (taking $(n_1, n_2, ...)$ to $\sum a_i n_i$ - which is a finite sum).

This defines a map
$$\prod_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}\to \operatorname{Hom}\left(\bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z} \right) $$
which you can check is a bijection (one nice way is to see if you can construct an inverse, hint: consider $\phi(0,..., 0, 1, 0,...)$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mummy. In your definition of $\varphi_a$ you have implicitely defined $\varphi_a$ on its generators via $\varphi(e_i) = a_i$, is that correct?

Comment: @Zest yes exactly, that's the idea. It's the reason it should be easy for you to find an inverse.

Answer (score 3):

Let $e_0=(1,0,0,...), e_1=(0,1,0,0,...), ...$ be the canonical free basis for $\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$. Define maps $$\phi:\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}\rightleftarrows\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}):\psi$$ by $\phi(a_0, a_1, ...)=\{(x_0, x_1,...)\mapsto\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}x_ia_i\}_{(x_0,x_1,...)\in\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\psi(f)=(f(e_0),f(e_1),f(e_2),...)$. Since elements of $\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ have only finitely many non-zero entries, $\phi$ is well-defined, and it is easy to check that both $\phi$ and $\psi$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-module maps. Because an element of $\text{Hom}(\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ is uniquely determined by its action on the basis elements $e_0, e_1, ...$, we see that $(\phi\circ\psi)(f)=f$, and it is also a straightforward calculation to see that $(\psi\circ\phi)(a_0, a_1, ...)=(a_0, a_1,...)$. Hence $\phi$ and $\psi$ are mutual inverses and thus isomorphisms.

Comment: Hi Atticus, thanks for your answer. In your definition of $\psi$, did you define $\psi(e_i) = a_i$? I am assuming that $(x_1,x_2,...)\mapsto \sum x_ia_i$ implies $\psi(e_i) = a_i$, is that correct?

Comment: Hi @Zest; so one should be a little careful by what one means by "$e_i$": in my answer I use it to mean an element of $\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$, not of $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$... the difference might seem pedantic but it's important insofar as the collection $\{e_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ forms a *basis* for $\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ but not for $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ (indeed, it is not even a generating set for $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$... for instance, the element $(1,1,1,\dots)\in\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ does not lie in the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of the $e_i$

Comment: So, because I am a bit of a pedant, just to be extra careful let's define $e'_i\in\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ to be the element of $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ that "looks like" the element $e_i$ of $\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have that $\psi(e'_i)$ is the *map* that takes $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots)\in\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ to $a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$... this is a little different than what you stated in your comment; does it make sense?

Comment: So it's not that $\psi(e'_i)$ is an integer $a_i$, it's that $\psi(e'_i)$ is a map from $\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\psi(e'_i)(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)=a_i$. Does this make sense?

Comment: It's crucial to note though that, to define $\psi$, it is not sufficient to merely define $\psi(e'_i)$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, because (as noted above) the $e'_i$ are not a generating set for $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, determining $\psi$ on the $e'_i$ will *not* in general determine $\psi$ on (for instance) the element $(1, 1, 1,\dots)\in\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thank you very much Atticus. Your comments together with your answer help me tremendously. I actually understand it now. My issue was that when i tried to reproduce what i've learned, i defined $\psi$ via $(x_1,x_2,...) \mapsto \sum x_i\psi(e_i)$ but when i tried to define the map $\phi$, things didn't work because picking an arbitrary element $(a_1,a_2,...)$ and sending it onto $\phi$ didn't work for obvious reasons. The key observation was that i needed to make sure to define all possible maps $\psi_\alpha$ inside the RHS. Thank you so much:)

Comment: @Zest my pleasure!! so happy it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the universal property of the direct sum of abelian groups says that any homomorphism $f$ from $\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_i$ to an abelian group $B$ corresponds to a family of homomorphisms $\{f_i\colon A_i\to B\mid i\in I\}$. Thus, you automatically have that
$$\mathrm{Hom}\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_i,B\right) \cong \prod_{i\in I}\mathrm{Hom}(A_i,B).$$
(Similarly, maps *into* the direct product correspond to families of maps into the factors, so $\mathrm{Hom}(B,\prod_{i\in I}A_i)\cong \prod_{i\in I}\mathrm{Hom}(B,A_i)$.)

So it just comes down to knowing that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$.